# Object losing it's type after passing to function in preloaded script

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, electron, tensorflow.js

I have a small desktop app, that displays the video feed from a camera, takes it's picture and passes it into a neural network.

When I take the image, it's type is `Tensor`, as expected, but after passing it into a function responsible for classifying it loses it's type and becomes a simple object.

The structure is as follows:

`CameraSource` <- Vue.js component, responsible for displaying video feed inside `<video>` element, and invoking the function

`ImageRecognizer` <- plain class, which uses `@tensorflow/tfjs-node`, and is preloaded into the window

Now the code is as follows :

CameraSource.vue

```
async test() {
      let vid: HTMLVideoElement = this.$refs.camera_preview as HTMLVideoElement;
      const img = tf.browser.fromPixels(vid);
      console.log(img); <- here it's a Tensor
      await window.api.test(img);
    }
```

image_recognition.ts

```
public async checkForObject(image: tf.Tensor): Promise<tf.Tensor<tf.Rank> | tf.Tensor<tf.Rank>[]> {
        console.log(image); <- here it lose's it's Tensor type, and becomes an object
        let reshaped = image.reshape([-1,720,1280,1]); <- this won't work, since image is not a Tensor
        return this.model.predict(image);
   }
```

preload.ts

```
const imageRecognizer = new ImageRecognition(720, 1280, 3);

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    test: (image: tf.Tensor): Promise<tf.Tensor<tf.Rank> | tf.Tensor<tf.Rank>[]> => {
        return imageRecognizer.checkForObject(image)
    }
});
```

type declaration

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        api: {
            test: (image: tf.Tensor) => Promise<tf.Tensor<tf.Rank> | tf.Tensor<tf.Rank>[]>
        }
    }
}
```

Is this happening because I'm trying to pass the object into the "backend" of the electron app? Is there any way to prevent this?

[Tensor losing it's type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yssOp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I should have read the documentation more carefully.

ContextBridge copies the values, so it can only handle some types. To use complex types, like `Tensor3D` it is recomended to serialize and deserialize the values respectively.

Everything is said here: [Electron contextBridge documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge#parameter--error--return-type-support)